# For which $p$'s does $\sum _{n\in \mathbb{N}}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(1+n)}\Bigr)^{p}$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

For which $p's \in \mathbb{R}_\geq1$ does the series $\sum _{n\in \mathbb{N}}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(1+n)}\Bigr)^{p}$ converge

**Thoughts** Clearly the sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(1+n)}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity, although that doesn't mean that much as we know $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. I've tried a few convergence tests such as the ratio test and found r=1 so that doesn't help, I've tried the integral test but can't see a way to integrate this function so I'm not really sure what to do now.

Comment: Have you tried Cauchy condensation test?

Comment: Comparison test would do all the work, maybe. The standards are $\sum 1/n^k$ for $k>1$ and $\sum 1/n$.

Comment: Okay so the comparison test shows that its either converges for all p's or it's diveges for all p's, going to try Cauchy condensation test for p=1 now.

Comment: No, the series converges for some $p,$ diverges for some $p.$

Comment: Can you explain why this is wrong then $\frac{\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(1+n)}\Bigg)^{p}}{\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(1+n)}\Bigg)^{1}}=\Bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\log(1+n)}\Bigg)^{p-1}$ which goes to $1 $ if $ p=1$ and $o$ if $\infty>p>1$ so by the comparison test I only need to look at $p=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Near $\infty$, the general term is equivalent to $\dfrac1{n^{p/2}\log^pn}$, which is a *Bertrand's series*.

Now, for the general Bertrand's series $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^\alpha (\log n)^\beta}$, it is known that it converges if and only if

- $\alpha>1$, or
- $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$.

Comment: Okay this makes it pretty clear that it converges for $p \geq 2$ still not 100% sure what I did wrong with the comparison test.

Comment: The problem is probably that the test to apply depends on the value of $p$. It's also the case for Bertrand's series: ffor $\alpha>1$ the comparison test works fine, and for `alpha=1$, we need the integral test.