# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\log n)^k}{n^p}$ convergent or not?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Direct comparison with $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$$ was tried.
So, my way to go at it was to do just have different cases, as in: assuming p>1, then solving it, then assuming p<1 and  then solving it again, however i could not solve it even after 2 hours of pondering over it. Tried to to do it with integral test, but it just ended up getting very complicated for me. its given that: k>0 and p>0.

Comment: Obviously the sum is over $n$

Comment: sorry, my bad, it was n not k.

Comment: What was the conclusion of the direct comparison tried? what is $k$?

Comment: i mean, the test totally depends on how these series compare, right?

Comment: And its given the k>0 and p>0, nothing else was given.

Comment: If $p>1$ the series converges, if $p<1$, the series diverges. If $p = 1$ and $k\geq -1$, the series diverges, if $p = 1$ and $k<-1$, the series converges.

Comment: what if p>1 and  k>1. what happens then? we cannot compare it with ∑1/n^p

Comment: If $p>1$ and $k > 1$?  You can compare to $\sum 1/n^q$ where $1 < q < p$.

Comment: Such an honor to have Nate Dogg on the site. I love your stuff with Eminem, Mr. Dogg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $k,p\ge 0$ :

**Case 1 : $p\le 1$**

Divergent, since for large enough $n$ $${(\log n)^k\over n^p}\ge {1\over n}$$

**Case 2 : $p>1$**

Convergent since for large enough $n$

$${(\log n)^k\over n^p}={(\log n)^k\over n^{p-1\over 2}}\cdot{1\over n^{p+1\over 2}}\le {1\over n^{p+1\over 2}}$$since $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{(\log n)^k\over n^{p-1\over 2}}=0$$and $\sum {1\over n^{p+1\over 2}}$ is convergent for $p>1$.

Comment: thank you for the answer. however does the value of k( whether k>1 or k<1) affect the convergence of the series?

Comment: Your welcome. Intuitively not because $n^p$ is much more dominating that $(\log n)^k$

Comment: In case $p=1$ the value of $k$ does make a difference.  If $k<-1$ then we get convergence, if $k \ge -1$, divergece.

Comment: I assumed $p,k>0$

Comment: You have a general answer for what is known as *Bertrand's series*. You can look at the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945871/for-which-ps-does-sum-n-in-mathbbn-bigl-frac1-sqrtn-log1n-b/2945930#2945930).